# Is it safe to use await in a for loop initialization?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, for-loop, async-await

Is it safe to use await in the initialization of a for loop?

```
let cursor = db.itemModels.find({}); 
for (let item = await cursor.next(); item != null; item = await cursor.next()) {
   // process the item
   ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use [`for await of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)?

Comment: @VLAZ Do you know if `cursor` supports async iteration? In contrast, OP's method can work with any Promise, even if it's not set up for `for await`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think so. [This article claims Mongoose supports async iterators](https://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-53-async-iterators.html).

Comment: If by safe you mean valid syntax, then yes it is safe to use `await`, just make sure your function is declared with the `async` keyword.

Comment: What would you imagine could be "unsafe" about it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code should be fine, but as mentioned by VLAZ, maybe you want to try an alternative approach `for await` since it was introduced to loop through  async iterable objects:

```
const cursor = db.itemModels.find({}); 
for await (let item of cursor.next()) {
// process the item     
...
}
```